# Emacs won't write to .emacs

Tags: init-file

I already checked around the stack exchange and internet for a while to why this issue is occurring, but I can't seem to find the solution.

Whenever I try to enable a disabled command in Emacs, it tells me the following:

```
Saving file c:/.emacs...
basic-save-buffer-2: Opening output file: Permission denied, c:/.emacs
```

I have no clue how to fix it because I thought that Emacs only loads it's .emacs on startup or when told to refresh and it wouldn't cause an issue.

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Does this happen when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)?

It looks like you do not have permission to save your init file at the top of the `C:\` drive (which is likely a good thing).  (In the old days, the top of the `C:\` drive was considered your home directory.  Nowadays, that's kind of frowned upon.)

When in Emacs, use `C-h r g init file` to go to the [Init File](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) page. There you will see where you can put your init file.

The first thing you should do, on MS Windows, is to define your `HOME` folder, which you do by defining the system (aka environment) variable `HOME`.  Then save your init file in that folder.

If your `HOME` variable is not already defined, or if you want to change your home-folder location, go to *Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables*.  Click *New* (if it is not yet defined) or *Edit* (if it is defined) and enter `HOME` as the *Variable name* and the location of the folder you want as the *Variable value*. Save your changes.

As the manual tells you, you can save your init file (in your `HOME` folder) in any of a few names:

> Emacs looks for your init file using the filenames `~/.emacs`, `~/.emacs.el`, or
>   `~/.emacs.d/init.el`; you can choose to use any one of these three names.  Here, `~/` stands for your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is very similar to Drew's but you need to keep in mind that whatever you set your `HOME` variable to one that you have permission of, such as `C:/Users/Your User/home/` so that emacs will be able to write to it, at least if you are setting it per user. That should fix it completely