# Emacs on Windows won't save

Tags: microsoft-windows, saving, permissions

I'm a total beginner to Emacs. I followed the tutorial that came with it, but when I tried to use `C-x C-s`, the echo area shows the message `Opening output file: Permission denied, c:/Program Files (x86)/Emacs/i686/bin/test8-22`

I believe I also tried saving to my own folder in `Documents` with no success. I've tried disabling and enabling `read-only-mode`, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. As far as I can tell, I have not modified Emacs in any way since I installed it.

Comment: Make sure that you can create a file (perhaps using some other editor) in your own folder. Assuming that that succeeds, then do the same thing with emacs *in that same folder*.

Comment: Have you defined your `HOME` environment variable in Windows? I think the conflict is with saving relative to `:c/` and not `HOME` (`~/`). I'll point you to another thread which better explains this, but this `HOME` environment variable needs to point to the folder where your `/.emacs.d` folder is located (i.e. where your `init` is) https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30473/35939 As a fellow user of emacs bound to Windows, I know it can be a pain to get up-and-running but it's worth it! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, and I fixed it by moving the EMACS folder into my user folder (example: `C:\Users\myUsername`). I think it's because the system doesn't let you create files in other places easily. BUT you can do it in your user folder.

Answer (score 0):

To amplify the existing answer, the “Program Files“ folder is off–limits; all programs will get a permission error if they try to write files there after installation. There are ways around that, if you really really want to, but you would probably be better off putting your personal documents into your personal “Documents” folder.

That can mean navigating to `C:/Users/<your user name>/Documents` before creating or opening any files. As others have mentioned, setting the `HOME` environment variable to your “Documents” folder will save you that step because Emacs will start you out in that folder.

You might wish to check out [chapter G.5 HOME and Startup Directories on MS-Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html) of the Emacs Manual, which goes over all of these and related details.